# CartoCSS: Don't show border between adjacent polygons

Tags: openstreetmap, polygon, tilemill, cartocss

In OSM, riverbeds are created as multiple adjacent or even overlapping polygons.

When styling these polygons in CartoCSS with a border, the overlapping can be seen:

[image: screenshot river with overlapping polygons]

I'd like to hide that line through the river. I guess that can be done either by merging the polygons, or by hiding the line between adjacent polygons.

Is that possible with CartoCSS / TileMill?

Comment: Try to use only fill for polygons (no emphasized outlines) and add some gamma as in https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/PolygonSymbolizer.